# Can a nineteen years old girl get divorce?

Tags: sharia, nikah, women, talaq

I am a 19 years old girl and I want divorce.
Does a girl's parent have any right to stop or force that girl from having divorce even if she wants a divorce from her husband?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assalamualaikum sister,

First of all, you should know that divorce is one of those acts, which are highly disliked by Allah and yet still permissible. In case of any issues between the husband and wife, they both should do anything to make this relationship work, but *only* if every single solution fails, and you are 100% sure that there is no hope for survival of the relationship, then it's your right to go for it. Thats the beauty of islam, that it gives you a solution in every possible problem.

Now coming to your point as to whether the parents can stop her from not getting divorce, please consider there might be a solid reason  why your parents don't want you to get a divorce. Parents are almost always wise and mature enough to think broadly, and as you are not much mature yet, at the age of 19, you definitely need help you in this **big** decision.  I would recommend that you should personally talk to them, and listen to their point of view as well, and why they don't want you to get divorce from your husband.

Secondly, Islam encourages us to always have consultancy in our issues. Even prophet Muhammad once, was getting consultancy from a group of sahaba, and he asked view of a child as well, about a battle, they were going to start. Sahaba asked that how can this child tell us anything good? then prophet Muhammad said that "Maybe he says something, which we might not know". So, please consult with elders of your family and his family as well.

If everything fails, then its my personal opinion (as I am not a scholar), as a woman cannot be forced to Marry anyone against her will, the same way no one can force any woman to stay in a relationship, that she personally doesn't want to stay in.

I would say that you should consult a scholar in this regard, as on this site with only common muslims present to answer, and with this being a very serious matter that will effect your whole life. So going *only* on the view of a non-scholar can be a big mistake.

Be very careful in this case.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: Farhan Brother thanks a lot. I asked another question too but don't lknow how to ask you specifically. I saw ur profile. But no option to ask further question to u. Have u got my Question.

Comment: I should say something my husband doesnt know how to eat properly don't know how to talk moreover he is rude with me. And overall less derserving for me. He is 28years old still he is very much immature. We face a lot of problem in understanding. There is a time when i need to get conjudally attached to him even if i don't want to. He sometimes forces me to do so. Though i tried a lot but love and respect towards him slowly faded when i started to know him more. I am not at all comfortable taking advices from my mom and dad. Please give me more advices. I just don't want my husband in my life.

Comment: @MalihaKarim: actually this question is not suited for this community. This community is specifically made fo asking Islamic question and not about resolution of personal matters. I hope you can understand it. and Sharing your personal problem on public forum like this,with your real name can be very dangerous.

Comment: Ohh extremely sorry for that! Didn't knew it i was just seeking in all sites for help and advice.

Comment: @MalihaKarim Asking advice is absolutely fine, however telling us this-and-that about you and your husband etc. can be dangerous

Answer (score 5):

No, women in general, regardless of age or any situation, *cannot divorce*. But *yes*, she can ask for *Khul' (خُلع in Arabic)*, or *"Take off"* literally.

1. [Please take this chosen response](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/10370/3846) as a serious advice.
2. [I did some researches](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/23180) and I found that [you are eligible for *Khul*](http://www.dd-sunnah.net/forum/showthread.php?t=40857) because in Islam Divorce is only for men, and women can only ask for *Khul'* from the Islamic Governor or anyone who's in this position (must be a Islamic scholar).
3. You may note that he (the Islamic Governor / Islamic judge) can refuse to divorce you and if so, of course he can see what you both didn't do and he'll guide you to finish all the process.

*Note:* When a woman ask for Khul' and gets it, she'll be required to pay the same amount of *"sidaq"* if you can of-course. This is [one of views](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/73322) in this case, and maybe the judge will take another view*

Comment: **Places to get educated :** [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khula) | [IslamHelpLine:Fatwa](http://www.islamhelpline.com/node/3729 "Fatwa") | [Siasat:Article](http://www.siasat.com/english/news/why-talaq-easy-khula-almost-impossible-muslim-society) | [SunniForum:Thread](http://www.sunniforum.com/forum/showthread.php?68683-Advice-on-Seperation-Divorce-Khula) << in this Forum be careful when you read, and always check the Madhab of the member.

Comment: This seems to be quite a hardline answer. If anyone else is in the situation of the OP, or even if the OP is reading this, please talk to any personal acquantences/relatives that you trust if you are truly unhappy in your marriage. If you feel that you are being abused, seek help from authorities. This website will not give you good answers in that regard.

Answer (score 3):

Nisa(4:35)-And if you fear dissension between the two, send an arbitrator from his people and an arbitrator from her people. If they both desire reconciliation, Allah will cause it between them. Indeed, Allah is ever knowing and Acquainted [with all things].

May Allah negotiate your troubles.

Answer (score 1):

If 19 years old girl can get married then why not she can get divorced?
Yes, you can get divorce anytime, either others like it or not. It's your right. You don't need to ask any scholar.
But question is why you want it? It's just an emotional decision or well thought decision?

Comment: She does not need to ask a Scholar? are you sure? Brother, do you think divorce is just like breaking relationship of a toy??? only EXPERTS should be consulted in Any case in life, so on what basis you are saying that EXPERTS should not be consulted? that if her parents can stop her from divorce or not?

Comment: Well said. But where do i find an Expert or scholar because i don't have that much independance to find one by myself.

Comment: @MalihaKarim: you can goto this website,and post your question, only expert scholars answer the questions there: http://islamqa.info/en

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I am not a brother but a sister. I live in Pakistan and have at least that much knowledge that being a women I have a right to have divorce. Why I need any scholar's verdict When my religion already granted me a right?

Comment: one more thing parents can not force either to get married or to get divorce, if they do so they do against the teachings of Islam. Even if her parents don't want her to take divorce they can not STOP it.They can explain her what is not good for her but again can not make her to do what she don't want.

Comment: Farhan brother, i asked a question in the website link u gave islamqa.info/en But i am confused will my answer appear in that particular site or it will b sent to my Gmail ?
Please clear my confusion.

Comment: @maliha usually you get an email response that will show where the question is answered.

Comment: @Farhan Some Islam SA users, me included, regard islamqa to be a website propagating extreme views. I urge those who visit external liks from answers and comments on Islam SA to be cautious about the source of what they see.

Comment: @A.Concerned.Lurker: They abide by laws of Quran and sunnah, so if sticking to Quran and sunnah is extremism,then i dont know what to say